# how to store polymorphic object in set

Tags: c++, c++11, set

how to define overloaded comparison operator or comparison functor, so that i can create the set of class A. i have a class Base which have int member variable _state and a derived class A.

```
#include <vector>
#include <set>
class Base{
int _state;
protected:
    virtual void fun() = 0;
public:
bool operator < (const Base & t)
{
return (this->_state < t._state);
}
    Base (int s): _state(s){}
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};

class A: public Base{
public:
    A(int s): Base(s){}
    void fun() override{}
    
};

int main()
{
    A a(5);
    
    std::set<A> s;
    
    s.insert(a);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: in the set nothing is polymorphic, its a set of `A`s.

Comment: For your interest, Polymorphism only works through pointers or references in C++.
So it should be `set<Base*>` if you want to store both `Base` and `A`

Comment: that's fine , but i have a set<A>, and i need to store class A objects in set.

Answer (score 4):

> how to define overloaded comparison operator or comparison functor, so that i can create the set of class A.

Set elements are const, and therefore such comparison operator must accept a const argument.

Your overloaded comparison operator does not accept a const left hand argument because you did not const qualify it. Solution: Add const qualifier:

```
bool operator < (const Base & t) const
```

I recommend not defining comparison operators as non-static member functions because they lack the symmetry of free functions. It would probably have been much less likely for you to have made the mistake of writing `bool operator < (Base & l, const Base & r)` because the symmetry makes the mistake obvious.

Comment: ok , but still not able to store the class A object in the set.

Comment: @sam Why do you think so?

Comment: the problem is : i have a class Base , contain a data member _status. Another class A is created from Base . Now i need to create a set to store object of class A.

Comment: @sam What makes that a problem?